# How do you access data that gets sent calling setsockopt in the Linux kernel's sock struct?

Tags: linux-kernel

For example I have a program that looks something like this:

```c
int data = 0xfff
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &data, sizeof(data))
```

In the Linux kernel-space where is the data actually located in the sock struct? I tried reading through `sock.h`, but haven't found anything where the `&data` variable would be kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this out by looking at [how the `setsockopt` syscall is implemented](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10/source/net/core/sock.c#L932). The `sock_valbool_flag()` function is used to set a bit in the bitmap `sk->sk_flags`. The bit used for `SO_KEEPALIVE` is `SOCK_KEEPOPEN`.

Given the above, you can check whether a socket (`struct sock *sk`) is keepalive or not through `sock_flag(sk, SOCK_KEEPOPEN)`, which returns the value of the bit. This is also how the `getsockopt` syscall does it.

Note: this is for kernel version 5.10, it might differ for your specific version, you should check for yourself.